# Excel 2013 Pivot Table Auto Sort Order

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that has multiple pivot tables calculating a % of compliance based on rows of data.  Every time I update the rows of data and refresh the pivot tables the % of compliance will change.  I want the pivot tables to be sorted from smallest % to largest %.  Currently, I have click on every pivot table and put it in sort order every time the workbook is refreshed.

Is there a way to set the pivot tables to ALWAYS sort the value A to Z when being refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to Automate the **Refresh & Sort process for all the Pivot Tables,** whenever ENTER or UPDATE Data, the below written VBA code can help you to do so.*

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim Wrkst As Excel.Worksheet
     Dim PvtBL As Excel.PivotTable

     For Each Wrkst In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pvtBL In Wrkst.PivotTables
          PvtBL.RefreshTable
            ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables().PivotFields("Sales").AutoSort _
                xlAscending, ActiveSheet.PivotTables(). _
                PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1)
        Next pvtBL
    Next Wrkst
 End Sub
```

**NB:** Since Field Name is not specified therefore I'm assuming Sales as Field to Sort, you can change it as and what you need.

*Hope this help you.*